# Problems typing in Russian (MiKTeX)

Tags: languages, babel

I'm trying to make a LaTeX file in Russian. I wrote the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

However, when I try to make a PDF out of it, I get

```
"Couldn't find 'larm10.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font larm1000.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It seems you are missing the Cyrillic font package. I suggest you to install the full version of MiKTeX 2.9. I suggest also to load `fontenc` before `inputenc` (it's necessary when using `utf8`, for instance).

Comment: Well I had no problems typing Hebrew with utf8... Should I save the .tex file in utf8 encoding?

Comment: It's better, if your editor supports it; but this won't solve the `larm1000` problem.

Comment: I just thought that if I could write Hebrew on the same machine, it means something. So I should download "The complete MiKTeX system" from http://miktex.org/2.9/setup ?

Comment: You could also try searching for the relevant packages with MiKTeX's Package Manager: install all that contains "cyrillic" (and also the CM-Super fonts).

Comment: I think you should update your babel package. Once you update this package, it works.
But, I get other problem that is the resolution of the output file is very bad. I submitted the same latex source code to the overleaf for compiling online, it gave a good output file with very good resolution (size of the output file was little bit bigger than mine). I'm trying to download and install all font package and hope that will solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The following MWE works for me and generates the image below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Здравствуйте}

Здравствуйте! Как у вас дела? Меня зовут Калеб. Как вас зовут?

\end{document}
```

[image: image of my MWE]

Perhaps installing the full [MiKTeX 2.9](http://miktex.org/) distribution or [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive) distribution will solve this issue.

If this does not work or if you simply cannot get it to work with LaTeX, you might want to consider using XeTeX. With XeTeX, you can use any of your system fonts in your document. Consider this MWE and the output it generates below.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra} % loads: fixltx2e, metalogo, xunicode, fontspec
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{PT Sans}

\begin{document}

\section{Здравствуйте}

Здравствуйте! Как у вас дела? Меня зовут Калеб. Как вас зовут?

\end{document}
```

[image: image of MWE with XeTeX]

Here I'm using [PT Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PT_Sans). Of course, you then might want to consider using [`polyglossia`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) instead of `babel`.

Comment: With the order `fontenc`, `inputenc`, `babel` I don't get the warning `Package babel Warning: No input encoding specified for Russian language`. That's why I recommend this loading order.

Comment: Well testing your first code gives me the same error but with larm12 and font larm 1200. As for XeTeX, that'd be my last option - I'd want to try solving it without it ... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should install at least the following MiKTeX packages:

```
cmcyr
cyrillic
cm-super
```

The first provides the Computer Modern Cyrillic fonts, which are required to begin typesetting in Russian. The second contains support files and the third provides the Type1 font files for better rendering and printing. It should be considered to install the full MiKTeX distribution and forget about downloading packages.

It's better also to use the UTF-8 encoding, if your editor supports it (and change editor if it doesn't). A typical file for typesetting in Russian starts as

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

If also English is needed (and the main language is Russian), then

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
```

is the better option (with T1 possibly omitted, which is instead necessary for other European languages written in the latin script).

The order `fontenc` `inputenc` `babel` avoids spurious warnings by Babel and makes sure that the correct encodings are chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I downloaded these 3 packages (and currently downloading full MiKTeX), but still got the same error... :-(

Comment: @Vlad Sorry, but I don't have any machine where I can try. I'll change the question's title to add the distribution, so it can attract experts with MiKTeX.