# MIKTeX cannot compile cyrillic (Bulgarian)

Tags: miktex, cyrillic

I'm typesetting a pretty simple excerpt of a math textbook, using pdfLaTeX on MIKTeX. I've only gotten this far:

```
\documentclass[openany,draft]{tagiis}
\begin{document}
%Стр. 112-115 номера на първата и последната от дадените стр.
\[ \int\limits_{\overline{a}}^b f(x)\,dx \geqq 0 \], \\
\[ \int\limits_a^{\overline{b}} f(x)\,dx \geqq 0 \].
Специално, ако функцията f(x) е интегруема, то
\[ \int\limits_a^b f(x)\,dx \geqq 0 \].
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--25

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.26 Спе
           циално, ако функцията f(x) е интегруе�...

?
```

If I remove the sentence in cyrillic it works just fine. Any suggestions for fixing this?

P.S. I've tried adding:

```
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference.
Also, I have installed all the packages from **Language Support -> Cyrillic**.

**EDIT:**
I don't know if this will help, but I loaded a file that my teacher gave me, which MIKTeX interprets as the following:

```
\documentclass[openany,draft]{tagiis}
\begin{document}
���. ���-��� ������ �� ������� � ���������� �� �������� ���.
\end{document}
```

This compiles perfectly...
If I open the file in a text editor it seems like a normal text file, just like the one I'm writing. If it helps - my text editor of choice is Notepad++.

Comment: Please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39212/problems-typing-in-russian-miktex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you add a link for the `tagiis` class? Does the problem happen also with `article`?

Comment: Thanks Papiro, but messing around with `inputenc` and `babel` doesn't seem to solve the problem.

egreg, it happens with `article` too.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the wrong encoding. If your text is encoded in UTF-8 and the unknown class `tagiis` loads `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}`, then the error at the third cyrillic letter can be explained:

`Спе` consists of the Unicode characters U+0421, U+043F and U+0435 in this order.
The following shows the bytes, if this is encoded in UTF-8 (hexadecimal values with decimal values in parentheses):

```
U+0421: 0xD0 (208), 0xA1 (161)
U+043F: 0xD0 (208), 0xBF (191)
U+0435: 0xD0 (208), 0xB5 (181)
```

Looking up `ansinew.def` we get:

```
\DeclareInputText{208}{\DH}
\DeclareInputText{161}{\textexclamdown}
\DeclareInputText{191}{\textquestiondown}
\DeclareInputMath{181}{\mu}
```

The latter is a *math* character and TeX complains about missing math mode (`Missing $ inserted`).

With class `article` and the right encoding the following works:

```
\documentclass[openany,draft]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\begin{document}
%Стр. 112-115 номера на първата и последната от дадените стр.
\[ \int\limits_{\overline{a}}^b f(x)\,dx \geq 0\,, \] \\
\[ \int\limits_a^{\overline{b}} f(x)\,dx \geq 0\,. \]
Специално, ако функцията f(x) е интегруема, то
\[ \int\limits_a^b f(x)\,dx \geq 0\,. \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remark:

- I have moved the punctuation into the equation. It looked too odd to me, if the punctuation was given on a separate line after the equation.

Comment: Actually this got another error: `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�� not set up for use with LaTeX.`

You were right about the encoding though, the problem was the encoding of the tex file. I changed it to `windows-1251` and it works like a charm, even without bothering with `inputenc` and `babel`.

Comment: @viksenpai: The key issue is telling LaTeX the **correct** encoding. If you encode your file in `windows-1251`, then it is no surprise that you get an error of package `inputenc`. If your class is using `\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}` and you tell your editor to save the file in `windows-1251`, then you have hit correct encoding settings.