# Text Justification right is Missing - Cyrillic Alphabet

Tags: unicode, sharelatex, cyrillic

I have a problem concerning the vertical alignment of text (containing macedonian cyrillic alphabet) at the right side using sharelatex. I also included `\selectlanguage{macedonian}` in the preamble, but it didnt change much. I am presenting below a minimal example. I will highly appreciate your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[macedonian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2a]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

На целата позитивна клима од разговорите, кои Нимиц ги нарече најдобри до  сега, сенка фрлија информациите од одредени грчки медиуми дека македонскатастрана наводно била подготвена да направи уставни промени.На целата позитивна клима од разговорите, кои Нимиц ги нарече најдобри до  сега, сенка фрлија информациите од одредени грчки медиуми дека македонската страна наводно била подготвена да направи уставни промени.

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i'm not quite sure what you mean by "text alignment right".  do you mean that the right margin is a straight line (like the left margin)?  that's known as "justification".  i don't have a tex system on this machine, so i can't test.  but i suspect that this may be related to the availability of proper hyphenation patterns for macedonian.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant the right margin, which for some reason is not a straight line. Is there a way to overcome the problem of the hyphenation ? Since it was impossible to get the cyrillic alphabet in the Texstudio and Latex I am usually using, I thought to go over to sharelatex, which worked good concerning the macedonian cyrillic alphabet, but the text justification at the right side is not good.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for hyphenation in Macedonian, unfortunately, so no word is hyphenated and you easily get overfull lines.

If Bulgarian is near enough, you can use its patterns:

```
% make Macedonian hyphenate like Bulgarian
\RequirePackage[macedonian=bulgarian]{hyphsubst}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[macedonian]{babel}

\begin{document}

На целата позитивна клима од разговорите, кои Нимиц ги нарече 
најдобри до  сега, сенка фрлија информациите од одредени грчки 
медиуми дека македонскатастрана наводно била подготвена да направи 
уставни промени. На целата позитивна клима од разговорите, 
кои Нимиц ги нарече најдобри до  сега, сенка фрлија информациите 
од одредени грчки медиуми дека македонската страна наводно била 
подготвена да направи уставни промени.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case some hyphen turns out to be wrong, you need to manually add `\-` at appropriate spots.

Comment: Many thanks. It worked very well (in sharelatex though). I am also wondering, why I cant use the macedonian cyrillic in the Latex installed in my computer (Miktex 2.9 and Texstudio). The exit of the compilation is: 'Process ended with errors', with no indication what errors is this about. The source code is pretty much the same as that I presented in the minimal example above. In the log file I found the following remark: "pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file larm1000): Font larm1000 at 600 not found ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!". Thanks for any comment.

Comment: @user159634 You have an incomplete MiKTeX installation. I'm not sure what are the packages you need to install. Try what's suggested at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39216/4427 (if it doesn't work, ask a new question).